# Nodejs create diffrent post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise, async-await

I’ve the following code which works when using standalone request (not promise all) , but I don’t know how can I send two request with different `form` data properties (see aaaa/bbbb exmaple)

e.g. this is what I need to pass for the first request (different scope)

```
formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
formData.append('scope', ‘aaaa’);
```

And this is to the **second** request (in the promise all)

```
formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
formData.append('scope', ‘bbbbb');
```

This is the code:

```
let [res1,res2] = await Promise.all([axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://oauth2.md/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic [userpassword]',
            ...formData.getHeaders()
        },
        data: formData
    },
    {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://oauth2.md/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic [userpassword]’,
            ...formData.getHeaders()
        },
        data: formData
    }
)])
console.log(res1.data.access_token)
```

Could I append it inline for each request? I try to put an object with those properties and it doesn't compile

is there a way to do something like this

```
    {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://oauth2.md/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic [userpassword]’,
            ...formData.getHeaders()
        },
         data: formData.append([{
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
            },{
                'scope': 'aaaa`
            }])

    }
```

**update:**

I've tried to do something like

```
let [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://oauth2.md/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic [userpassword]',
            ...formA.getHeaders()
        },
        data: formA
    }),
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://oauth2.md/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic [userpassword]',
            ...formB.getHeaders()
        },
        data: formB
    })
])
```

console.log(res1.data.access_token)

```
function formA() {
         
    formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    formData.append('scope', 'aaaa');           
    return formData     
} 




function formB() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    formData.append('scope', 'bbbb');           
    return formData     
}
```

Which doesn't work, now if I create the object inside like it works but the **code is ugly**, is there a better way to achieve this

```
function formB() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    formData.append('scope', 'bbbb');           
    return formData     
}
```

Comment: One axios object cannot take multiple request, try using different axios object for multiple request, you should be able to do as you intended.

Comment: @vikashvik - I've update my question please have a look

Comment: Can you replace data: formA with data: formA().  Function should be called with parentheses.

Comment: @vikashvik - sorry I didnt get it. it's working if I create the instance inside each formA and formB, however it's a bit ugly, is there a better way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there.

The main problem is that the `axios` function needs to be called multiple times in the `Promise.all` function.

With the above solved, my last recommendation is to make separate form-data objects for each request.

For example:

```js
var formData1 = getFormDataObjectSomehow()
var formData2 = getAnotherFormDataObjectSomehow()

let [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://oauth2.md/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic [userpassword]',
            ...formData1.getHeaders()
        },
        data: formData1
    }),
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://oauth2.md/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic [userpassword]',
            ...formData2.getHeaders()
        },
        data: formData2
    })
])

console.log(res1.data.access_token)
```

EDIT:
And don't forget to handle errors thrown from the `axios` requests. Either add `.catch()` block to your `Promise.all` or use a `try/catch` guard.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it. there is no way to put it inline ? I mean inside each of the objects

Comment: Thanks but its not working , I think its becose  `function formA() {
        formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
        formData.append('scope', 'aaaa');
        return formData
    }

    function formB() {
        formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
        formData.append('scope', 'bbb');
        return formData
    }`